# Does Neary Vowel Normalization account for Vocal Tract Length?

Tags: vowels

Can't quite find this in the research I have done so far that surveys various vowel normalization methods...

Comment: Your question basically consists only of the title. Can you elaborate a bit more on what you'd like to know? This will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_estimate_a_persons_vocal_tract_length_using_a_recorded_audio_file) by Richard Wright indicates that it does, assuming a "a fairly thorough and evenly distributed set of vowels", and similarly [this summary](http://lingtools.uoregon.edu/norm/norm1_methods.php#nearey) says it performs well in reducing variation from physiological differences. By "account for", I assume you mean "effectively control for", since actual vocal tract length measurements cannot be part of the computation.